Movelt Setup Assistant を実行した際のエラーについて
Movelt Setup Assistantを実行しようと、
/home/ユーザ名/Downloads/franka_ros-develop/franka_description/robots/panda/panda.urdf.xacro
/home/ユーザ名/Downloads/franka_ros-develop/franka_description/robots/panda/panda.urdf.xacro

をLoadし、optional xacro arguments欄に
hand:=true
を入力すると以下のエラーを出しました。
Running xacro failed.

Please check console for errors.
Running xacro failed.
Please check console for errors.
この場合、何が原因でどう解決すればよいのでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。
